# how to mark a particular location in Google maps from my android app

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am creating an app common for both iphone and android . In my iPhone app i am using the default map of my device which shows the terrain, satellite regions. There i am able to show the current location of the user and the another geo point of a place with a marker.

In the same way in my android app i want to show the traffic, terrain and satellite so i am using the google map. In this i am able to show my current location but how can i show another location that too marked by a marker.

Can anyone help me in this, pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an Overlay that handles all my user gestures ... long presses, double-clicks, etc.  Based on what the user does I'll grab the Lat/Long of that pixel location and get the GeoPoint of it and query Google's service for the actual address.  From there it's typical Android MapActivity development.  You can paint as manyy overlays as you want on the screen to indicate multiple places of interest.

Lot's of samples on the net on this topic.